# Is there any API MacBook to get clamshell mode?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors

I want to make a small utility which makes my MacBook to get clamshell mode.
Is there any usable API?

Clamshell means 'only external monitor on mode'.
This is the behaviors what I want.

1. Both of internal/external monitors on
2. Use the utility
3. Internal monitor off/externals on.

Comment: I would post this question in superuser.com to try to find some existing tool to perform the task. Then, if you need to implement this yourself, come back for help on how to programatically use that utility. It seems to me as if this is more closely related to system configs than to programming.

Comment: You're right. I already asked this there too. But It's pretty hard to find the exact utility what I want. (I have been found this one several months) So I'm asking about APIs. This is almost my last try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call [pmset](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) from your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I read the linked documentation, but I couldn't find about single monitor off. Maybe I missed the content or my question is unclear.
I modified the question to clarify the problem. If I missed the content, could you help me know the point?